# Using jQuery.each() to manipulate the elements of an Array/Object in place

Tags: javascript, jquery

Playing around with JavaScript and jQuery over here. Making a function that produces timestamps.

I've got the following code:

```
var timestamp = function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var components = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()];

    components.zero_pad = function(index, component) {
        // When this function is called with `$.each()` below, 
        // `this` is bound to `component`, not `components`.
        // So, this code fails, because you can't index a Number.
        this[index] = (this[index].toString().length == 1) ?
          '0' + component : component;
    }

    // Offending line
    $.each(components, components.zero_pad);
    return components[0] + ':' + components[1] + ':' + components[2];
};
```

This code fails, because, `$.each()` binds the callback to the element it's working on rather than the iterable, as  such:

```
// from jQuery.each()
for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
    // I would have guessed it would be 
    // value = callback.call( obj, i, obj[ i ] );
    // but instead it's:
    value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

    if ( value === false ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, to get the binding I want, I can change the offending line in my code to:

```
$.each(components, $.proxy(components.zero_pad, components));
```

but here I invoke even more framework code and this is starting to look quite messy.

I feel like I'm missing something! Is there a simpler way to modify the contents of an array in place?

Comment: To clarify, I feel like instead of `$.each` and then `$.proxy`, I could just write my own `for` loop, with the `call` I want.

Comment: you can extend the Array.prototype.zero_pad = function(){};

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to replace all your `zero_pad` stuff with something simpler, like this:

```
var timestamp = function() {
  var now = new Date(), parts = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()],
      pad = function(n) {return n < 10 ? "0"+n : n;};
  return pad(parts[0])+":"+pad(parts[1])+":"+pad(parts[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kolink! That's a good point. I guess I should have changed the code to be more generic though, because this question is more about the best/simplest way to modify an Array/Object in place. What do you think of .map(), as james emanon points out above?

Comment: `.map` is good, but only if the browser supports it. You could always just loop: `for( i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {arr[i] = doSomething(arr[i]);}`

Answer (score 0):

please ignore the following if I'm off base- but I was curious what you were trying to get at, is this "sorta" what you are trying to achieve?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var now = new Date();
   var components = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()];
   var timestamp = {
     storage : {},
         zero_pad : function() {
            storage = $.grep(components,function(obj,i){
            return obj = (obj.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + components  : components;
         });
        return storage;
     }
   };
     console.log(timestamp.zero_pad());
 });
```

Comment: Hi james, thanks for the response. Not sure why you're using `.grep` here. Earlier you suggested `jQuery.map`, and here you're using `.grep` like `.map`, since the `.grep` callback will never return falsey. So, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I was just trying different things.. ie. grep. I also did one with .map() just messing around, but just happend to post the grep one. Actually, I'm pooped out so I might have missed cut/paste.. I apologize. long day.

Comment: Hey man! No need to apologize :D. I appreciate your help and looking into this. Thank you!